# How to keep Visual Studio from replacing open file with file in search results

Tags: visual-studio

Suppose I have a file open in VS.  I then do a search (ctrl + F) in, say, the entire solution.  I click on a result in the search results window.  It replaces the file that I have open with the file in my search results.  I then have to search for the file it replaced and re-open it.   How do I tell VS not to replace the file I have open with the file I have clicked on in search results, but instead to open the clicked on result in a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the tab in the upper-right corner, if you hover there is a tool-tip that says to click to keep the tab open.  This must be done before clicking on the result of another search.